# How do I animate a large circle resizing down to a small circle on Long Press in Flutter?

Tags: animation, resize, flutter

I want to animate a large circle/image resizing down into a small circle/image using Flutter.

The small circle would be resized directly onto the pointer/my finger, and follow the pointer as it moves.

My first instinct is to use a GestureDetector's `onLongPress` but I'm not really sure how to tell the circle to adjust its radius and have it follow the pointer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should includie details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [LongPressDraggable widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LongPressDraggable-class.html). Here is a sample (assume currentHeight/currentWidth/circkeDiameter have already been defined):

```
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
Animation animation = new AnimationController();
new AnimatedBuilder(
 controller: animation,
 child: new Container(),
 builder: (_, Widget child) {
   return new Container(
     width: lerpDouble(currentWidth, circleDiameter, animation.value),
     height: lerpDouble(currentHeight, circleDiameter, animation.value),
     child: new ClipRRect(
       borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(
         (circleDiameter / 2.0) * animation.value,
       ),
       child: child,
     ),
   );
 });
```

and here is an example: https://github.com/fuchsia-mirror/modules-video/blob/master/modules/video/lib/src/widgets/screen.dart#L87

If you didn't care about the small circle following your pointer as you drag (i.e. you just want to see the resizing animation), you could maybe use an AnimatedCrossFade widget, whose crossFadeState uses a flag that is set by a GestureDetector's onLongPress. E.g. something like:

```
bool didLongPress = false;
return new GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: setDidLongPressToTrue(),
    child: new AnimatedCrossFade(
      duration: someAnimationTime,
      firstChild: largeCircle,
      secondChild: smallCircle,
      crossFadeState: didLongPressed
          ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
          : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
    ),
);
```